# I tried to write a function that checks if two arrays are permutation of each other

Tags: c, arrays

by using counting. It's given that the values of the arrays can be only between 1 and 100. Its seems that my function is not right I dont understand why.
Here is my function:

```
int CheckPermutation3(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size)
{
    int count1[100], count2[100]; //the size 100 because in that case values are only between 1 and 100//
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        count1[i]=0;
       count2[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)  //counting the elements of each array//
       count1[arr1[i]]++;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        count2[arr2[i]]++;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)   //comparison//
        if (count1[i]!= count2[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is not the way. Sort and compare.

Comment: What convinces you that your function isn't right? It looks perfectly fine, assuming the data is within the described range. Did you use any specific data for testing it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. There is nothing wrong with counting if there is a limited range of integer values.

Comment: @AlexD I agree (BTW, counting sort is pretty much it is). Probably "not the way" should be replaced with "not the best and generic way.."

Comment: If the array entries range from 1 to 100 you'll better subtract one when using them as subscript. Else, with 100, you go out of range.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation: the only reason it wouldn't work is if items were out of range, because this would cause undefined behavior.

You can somewhat simplify the code by using a single array, like this:

```
int balance[100] = {0}; // Initialize all elements to zero
for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
    balance[arr1[i]-1]++;
    balance[arr2[i]-1]--;
}
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
    if (balance[i] != 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
```

Comment: Do `arrx[i]-1`, since numbers range from 1 to 100 (and not from 0 to 99).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be only 1 problem why it may not work.

You are storing value between 1 and 100 [Inclusive, I guess] in an array with indexes [0-99].
So, if arr1[i] value is 100, it'd break here. 
`count1[arr1[i]]++;`
as you are trying to increment count1[100] which is out of range. 
Similarly, if arr2[i] value is 100, it'd break here. 
`count2[arr2[i]]++;`

To fix this: 
1. Create an array of 101 size. 
2. Iterate from 1 to 100 [inclusive] 
`for(i=1;i<=100;i++)   //comparison//
        if (count1[i]!= count2[i])
            return 0;`

If you want to save some space, let the array be of size 100,
and do this 
`count1[arr1[i]-1]++;` 
Similarly, for arr2 
`count2[arr2[i]-1]++;`

This way you are storing each value in it's prev value's place in array. [0th indexing]

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What did you try and what didn't work? Also update the question with test case that is failing.

Comment: Glad to help. Please close this by accepting/upvoting the answer.